# python variable not updating when passed through functions

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters, arguments

I have the functions below on a variation of the subbset_sum problem

```
def findFourPlus(itemCount, seq, goal):
    goalDifference = float("inf")
    closestPartial = []
    subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial=[])
    print(closestPartial)


def subset_sum(itemCount, seq, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if(len(partial) == itemCount):
        if s == goal:
                print("FOUND YAA")
                print(partial)

        else:
            if( abs(goal - s) < goalDifference):
                #print(abs(goal-s), goalDifference, closestPartial)
                goalDifference = abs(goal - s)
                closestPartial[:] = partial
                #print(abs(goal-s), goalDifference, closestPartial)

    for i in range(len(seq)):
        n = seq[i]
        remaining = seq[i+1:]
        subset_sum(itemCount, remaining, goal, goalDifference, closestPartial, partial + [n])
```

My previous problem was that closestPartial was not updating (returns an empty list) even though I'm trying to mutate it in subset_sum. That was solved now. Now I have a similar problem, my goal Difference is also not updating, as it is forever returning infinite.

In the subset_sum function, I am trying to update **goalDifference**, and when I print out some test outputs it does appear it is updating, but I assume that every time I pass the recursion call, the value is lost again, rendering **goalDifference** back to infinite each time.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Numbers are immutable - `goalDifference = abs(goal - s)` doesn't change the object, it reassigns the name. You need to `return` the new value and assign it back: `goalDifference = subset_sum(...)`.

Comment: Even if numbers were mutable, the line `goalDifference = abs(goal - s)` would still just reassign a new value to the name `goalDifference`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, when I changed the line print(partial) to return partial, it does not return anything in the shell. The print("found yaa") still prints, but nothing is returned. any ideas why?

Comment: read up on variable scopes